# winapi - GetServiceKeyName returns empty service name

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get service name from display name using winapi function GetServiceKeyName in C++ with the following code:

```
SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL,
                                     NULL, // service control manager database
                                     SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE |SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS | STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ);

LPTSTR lpServiceName;
LPCTSTR lpDisplayName = L"My service";
DWORD dwSizeNeeded = sizeof(lpDisplayName);

GetServiceKeyName(hSCManager, lpDisplayName, lpServiceName, &dwSizeNeeded);
```

After finish, dwSizeNeeded have 15 as value and lpServiceName have "". Where I'm wrong calling to this function? Need any special right here? The inconvenience here is that this app doesn't have admin rights so I cannot (I guess) set **SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS**. Of course, My service is up and running in system, so I have not bad display name.

Comment: You have a pointer `lpServiceName`, but *where does it point*? The [`GetServiceKeyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683229(v=vs.85).aspx) function doesn't allocate memory for this, it assumes you pass in an existing buffer (like an array). Furthermore, the `dwSizeNeeded` argument should be initialized to the size of the buffer for the `lpServiceName` argument.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude It is an out param. Is this necessary?

Comment: @someprogrammerdude so, you suggest initialize lpServiceName as an empty array or fixed size array? And how I can initialize dwSizeNeeded if I don't know what value does it have? Please if you can paste some code example would much appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty much always a mistake to neglect to check for errors. Why didn't you check for errors as is clearly explained in the documentation? It says: *If the functions succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.* Is there a good reason for ignoring this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two lines needs to be modified:

```
...
TCHAR lpServiceName[512];
DWORD dwSizeNeeded = sizeof lpServcieName / sizeof lpServiceName[0];  // Number of elements in buffer
...
```

You should also see what [`GetServiceKeyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683229(v=vs.85).aspx) *returns* as that is the signal if it has succeeded or not. Checking the string is only valid if `GetServiceKeyName` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: This is one of those API calls that you usually call twice: Once with an invalid buffer (`NULL`) of size 0, to determine the required size, followed by a second call passing an appropriately sized buffer.